# UART STM32L0, Parity bit implementation

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stm32

I am setting up communication via USART2 Asynchronous to receive my data. Configuration for receive the data is 9600/7bit/1-bit stop/Parity Even/Mode Rx/Tx. The implementation works fine when no parity is implemented. But the specification dictates that even parity should be supported.

If added the parity, I received any value.I do not understand where is the problem.

My configuration is with STMCubeMx for STM32L031K6 nucleo.

```
    void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
    {

      huart2.Instance = USART2;
      huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
      huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_7B;
      huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_RX;
      huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
      huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit =    UART_ADVFEATURE_RXOVERRUNDISABLE_INIT|UART_ADVFEATURE_DMADISABLEONERROR_INIT;
      huart2.AdvancedInit.OverrunDisable = UART_ADVFEATURE_OVERRUN_DISABLE;
      huart2.AdvancedInit.DMADisableonRxError = UART_ADVFEATURE_DMA_DISABLEONRXERROR;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }

    }

    void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
    {

      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
      if(uartHandle->Instance==USART2)
      {
        /* Peripheral clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

        /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
        PA9     ------> USART2_TX
        PA10     ------> USART2_RX 
        */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        /* Peripheral interrupt init */
        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
      }
    }

    void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
    {

      if(uartHandle->Instance==USART2)
      {
        /* Peripheral clock disable */
        __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_DISABLE();

        /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
        PA9     ------> USART2_TX
        PA10     ------> USART2_RX 
        */
        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10);

        /* Peripheral interrupt Deinit*/
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

      }
    } 

void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
/*********************** interruption **********************/ 

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART2)  //current UART
        {   
            Receive();
            HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, Rx_data, 1);   
        }
}

/******************** Main ******************************/
int main(void)
{
  HW_Init();
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, Rx_data, 1); 
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: 7bits plus parity is equal to 8bits transmission, so try `huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_7B` --> `huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B`

Comment: Can you link to the data sheet for the thing you are trying to talk to over the usart?  Or are you not getting any bits out at all?

Comment: What does "I received any value." mean?  What is on the other ends of the cable in your tests, and how is that configured??  What can you learn by examining the UART status flags?

Comment: Is the other end configured the same as your end. If it works ok before you set even parity, but not so afterwards I suspect the other end may not have even parity set. As Chris states above check the UART flags, have you now got a parity error? (if so the data will be thrown away!)

Answer (score 3):

When using parity on STM32 series, you need to increase the UART_WORDLENGTH_7B to UART_WORDLENGTH_8B (or UART_WORDLENGTH_9B if you have 8 bits of data).

I just experienced the same problem myself recently. The HAL API should been better at this point...

Comment: it is not the HAL - it how the STM32 UARTs are programmed on the low level. The word length includes the parity bit if enabled. If you have  read the uC documentation and did not relay on the "abstraction", you will know it. This one of the reasons why I do not like HAL. It gives the very false impression that people using it do not have to know the hardware.

Comment: The HAL API is to make the hardware easier to use, so they could easily named the constants DATALENGTH and increased by one if parity was used

Answer (score 0):

Quick related note: If changing parity on the fly (in code), you must disable the UART first, by clearing CR1.UE. If not, the config bits in CR1 will not 'stick'.  This is best done by using the Init method. e.g.,

```
huart1.Init.Parity = parity;
huart1.Init.WordLength = wordLength;
HAL_UART_Abort(&huart1);
HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);
```

Using UART_Config is ok for baud rate changes, but not parity.

Hopefully this will save someone the 1.5 days it cost me. Not obvious in ref manuals.